# can i use redux-form without using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm new to react while am validating forms I heard about redux form. here I got confused while searching about it. is it depended on redux not? Can I use redux-form without redux? if yes can anyone help how to use it?

Comment: No, redux is necessary

Comment: You can use forms without using redux-form! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be used together with Redux *and* React.

As the description says,

> A Higher Order Component using react-redux to keep form state in a Redux store

Generally, it's expected that something with 'redux' in title won't work without Redux, otherwise this would be a terrible name for a package.

If a package is advertised to be useable with Redux but isn't limited to it, its name doesn't contain 'redux'. The example is [`immer`](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer).

Comment: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/630774054237175808?lang=en  i got confused after reading that tweet.

Comment: This means that `react` and `redux` packages they aren't installed automatically with it. They are `peerDependencies` and not `dependencies`. This helps to avoid problems with dependency versions. E.g. there's a good chance that you can use redux-form with newer React and Redux without updating it if newer version of it has breaking changes.